# Trouble with a lot of HTML code inside an innerHTML command

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently writing a simple JS function inside a JS File called GeneralJS 
that is supposed to execute a slidebar. The function looks like this

```
function LoadSideBar() { document.getElementById("sideBarDiv").innerHTML = "<div data-role="panel" data-position="left" data-position-fixed="false" data-display="reveal" id="nav-panel" data-theme="a">
        <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-theme="e" data-icon="home" > 1</a><br/>
        <a href="NewTask.html" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="plus" > 2</a><br/>
        <a href="JoinGroups.html" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="search" > 3</a><br/>
        <a href="Groups.html" data-role="button"  data-theme="b" data-icon="grid" > 4</a><br/>
        <a href="Settings.html" data-role="button"  data-theme="b" data-icon="gear" > 5</a><br/>
        <a href="" data-role="button"  data-theme="b" data-icon="info" > 6 </a><br/>
        <a href="" data-role="button"  data-theme="b" data-icon="arrow-r" > 7 Us </a><br/>
        <a href="" data-role="button"  data-theme="b" data-icon="minus" > 8 </a>
            </div>";
}
```

The HTML executing code is `<script src="GeneralJS.js"> </script>
        <script> LoadSideBar() </script>`

The problem seems to be that after the .innerHTML = i put a lot of HTML code inside the quotes because when I change the HTML code to `"<h1> Hi </h1>"` everything works. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Check your console.... You have not used the quotes properly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're defining this long string enclosed with double quotes (`"`), which are also in the html code you're trying to put in the string, and so the string is stopped after the first quote in the html code. This can be easily fixed by defining the string using single quotes (`'`) because the html code doesn't use them:

```
function LoadSideBar() { document.getElementById("sideBarDiv").innerHTML = '<div data-role="panel" data-position="left" data-position-fixed="false" data-display="reveal" id="nav-panel" data-theme="a"> <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-theme="e" data-icon="home" > 1</a><br/> <a href="NewTask.html" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="plus" > 2</a><br/> <a href="JoinGroups.html" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="search" > 3</a><br/> <a href="Groups.html" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="grid" > 4</a><br/> <a href="Settings.html" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="gear" > 5</a><br/> <a href="" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="info" > 6 </a><br/> <a href="" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="arrow-r" > 7 Us </a><br/> <a href="" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="minus" > 8 </a> </div>'; }
```